# Specifying 'Where' keyword with numeric types

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this and my current implementation is clunky. I have a generic method in my class that applies a numeric value to a combo box's Value property. I would like this method to work for ints, floats, decimals, and doubles. Internally it will cast to a decimal. Here is my code currently:

```
private void UpdateValueFromComboBox<T>(ComboBox tSource, NumericUpDown tDest)
{
    NamedKeyValuePair<String, T> tKV = tSource.SelectedItem as NamedKeyValuePair<String, T>;
    if (tKV != null)
    {
        // Update the Control's value with what was saved
        tDest.Value = Decimal.Parse(tKV.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get rid of the ToString() and Parse() calls. Basically, I want the assignment to be as follows:

```
tDest.Value = (Decimal) tKV.Value;
```

But because C# doesn't know what 'T' is or will be, it gives me an error. I get an error that "Cannot convert type 'T' to 'decimal'". Is there a way to specify, using the Where keyword, that the values being passed in are numeric??

Comment: tDest.Value = (Decimal)(object)tKV.Value

Comment: @dkackman: That won't work if it's any other numeric type.  If you're doing that, you might as well make it non-generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Instead, you can add `where T : struct, IConvertible` and call `tKV.Value.ToDecimal(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not built in:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=numeric+generic+C%23

You could try `Convert.ToDeciaml(tKV.Value)` since it takes an `object` as a parameter.